# How does EtherDelta migrates mapping?

Tags: solidity, mapping, etherdelta, migration

I'm looking at [EtherDelta contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819#code),  and -- provided it had been migrated several times in the past and probably foresees future migrations -- I'm confused as I don't see any method by which the owner of the contract can migrate the `balances` data. 
They must have a list of all the addresses in the mapping in order to migrate the data to a new version of the contract, don't they? Yet it is missing from the contract.

Can someone suggest what they do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't do any type of migration. People have to withdraw from the old version and move to the new version when there's an update. You can even go back and use the old versions AFAIK.

Comment: wow usability at its best!

Comment: @shaharsol that's the price of immutable, decentralized systems. forced migration would no longer be decentralized